# does blobstore create blobInfo when using create_gs_key ?google app egine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am using `create_gs_key` to create blobestores keys for files in the cloud storage.

according to 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

I can't get bloblInfo.

but when I try to get bloblInof from the `create_gs_key` returned key , I get blobInfo object(with size,and md5 but without fileName) ?

Comment: In the SDK a BlobInfo object is created without the filename. But when you upload your application no BlobInfo object will be created.

Comment: no I am not talking about the SDK ! that's right there is no blobInfo object will be created, but if you try within your code to get the blobInfo then the size, you will get it...

Comment: Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/  However, BlobInfo objects are currently not available for GCS objects.

Comment: @voscausa yes I read that, and I post the same link in my question, but in practice I got blobInfo that has md5 and size ... maybe this's bug ?? you can try it ...

Comment: Don't bother and don't use it. Here is how I use GCS: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python

Comment: @voscausa thank you,could  you please help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105509/how-to-search-structured-properties-google-app-engine

Answer (score 2):

No it does not create a BlobInfo - it just creates a BlobKey that you can then use in the various functions that accept a BlobKey as their argument.

Comment: but , when I tried to get the bloblInfo then the property size, I get it.... that's right that I could not search this blobInfo in DatastoreViwer but it's exist ???