# How to search structured properties ? google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, data-structures, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I have two models categories and cities:

```
class category(ndb.Model):
      hidden = ndb.BooleanProperty()
      categoryName = ndb.StringProperty()

class city(ndb.Model):
      categories = ndb.StructuredProperty(category,repeated = True)
      cityName = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I have cityEntity:
How to return categories list that contain just category.hidden = false ?

edit:
it's possible to get the categories list, then Loop through the categories list and extract just the categories which not hidden

for example I have city entity:

```
categories_unhidden_list = []
for category in city.categories :
    if not category.hidden :
        categories_unhidden_list.append(category)
```

but I would like to get the categories_unhidden_list from the datastore !

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties

Comment: @voscausa thank you, but that doesn't return the categories list, that return the city entity, I edit the question to clarify !

Comment: Yes, a query returns whole entities containing ...(where you queried for). From the filtered entities you can extract the category list for list processing.

Comment: ummm, ok thank you, I just thought that the datastore could return the filtered list,( without doing that doing that in my code), because the datastore could do that more efficiently .

Answer (score 0):

A query will match only what is queried for. If the entity fulfills the condition, it will return the entity. If you have a repeated property and a query matches one of the values, it will return the whole list in the entity, not only the one that matches. This is why repeated properties should almost always be either a key, a simple value, or a simple key value pair.

You may want to look into A) [projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries) and B) structuring your data so that you can query for categories that have a value of `x` and a parent-entity of `key_y`, instead of querying for Y's where they have `key_x` in their repeated list.